# Возможно ли распарсить программу на языке Си с помощью LL(1) парсера?

Tags: c, синтаксический-анализ

Возможно ли распарсить программу на языке Си с помощью LL(1) парсера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет.

Грамматика C не является контекстно-свободной. Например, выражение

```
a((b)*c);
```

может являться

- если `a` — функция, `b` — тип, `c` — указатель: разыменование указателя `c`, приведение результата к типу `b`, передача полученного значения как параметра в функцию `a`;
- если `a` — функция, `b` — числовая переменная/константа, `c` — числовая переменная/константа: умножение значений `b` и `c`, передача полученного значения как параметра в функцию `a`.

Таким образом, правильный разбор невозможен без контекста. LL-парсеры предназначены лишь для контекстно-свободных грамматик.

Comment: И какой же тогда парсер порекомендуете использовать?

Comment: Я бы взял lex/yacc (flex/bison), ввёл явный контекст, разрешил неоднозначности вручную.

Comment: @SoloMio Вот грамматика для ANTLR 4 https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

Comment: @Андрей:

    typedefName
        : Identifier
        ;

Что-то мне не кажется эта грамматика однозначной. Как она отличит два случая из моего ответа?

Comment: @VladD, а что имеется в виду под явным контекстом?

Comment: @SoloMio: ну, например, текущий namespace: отображение имени в объект, чтобы вы смогли выяснить, является идентификатор именем типа или именем переменной.